# Is it valid to use random numbers in parallel Stream#filter?

Tags: java, random, java-stream

The problem is to take an input collection, filter it randomly (e.g. include all elements with 50% probability, otherwise skip them). This can be done with a regular for cycle in the following way:

```
Random random = new Random();
List<Object> list;    // suppose that this list is populated with some elements
List<Object> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i  = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    if (random.nextDouble() < 0.5) {
        filteredList.add(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

When the code above is rewritten to Java 8 streams, it could look something like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
List<Object> list;
List<Object> filteredList = list.stream()
    .filter(element -> random.nextDouble() < 0.5)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My question is if this is a valid approach when using `Collection#parallelStream` instead of `Collection#stream`. By valid approach I mean mainly that the number will really be pseudorandom - wouldn't the randomness be impacted by reusing the same object in multiple threads? And would using `ThreadLocalRandom#current` make a difference? My gut feeling is that reusing the same object created outside of the stream could have an impact, where as creating the instance in the filter method

```
.filter(element -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble() < 0.5)
```

is the preferred way. Or is there any major point I am missing?

**EDIT:** If getting the random instance via `ThreadLocalRandom#current` in the `filter` method is the correct approach, what would happen if I did instantiate it beforehand and use the same instance (as seen in the first code example)? Would concurrent calls to `nextDouble` from different threads return the same numbers?

Comment: just notice that your source list would have to be *huge* for `parallel` to make any impact

Comment: Yes, that should be taken into consideration as well. This is more a general behaviour question rather than something related to a problem I've encountered. However, I think that the number of threads used is more relevant than the size of the list, as that is what causes the concurrent access.

Comment: I meant for the timing of the entire operation... adding `parallel` for a list with not so many elements, will only introduce delays due to threading scheduling, etc and you will get slower results than non-parallel

Comment: By allocating the instance before the filter invocation, you completely disable the functionality of `ThreadLocalRandom`. `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` returns a new object for each Thread, and only during parallel invocation, it would be called by different threads. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Instances of `java.util.Random` are threadsafe. However, the concurrent
>   use of the same `java.util.Random` instance across threads may encounter
>   contention and consequent poor performance. Consider instead using
>   `ThreadLocalRandom` in multithreaded designs.

The only case in which pseudorandomness breaks is when you initialize different random sources on different threads with the same seed (eg. when you use current time as the seed and then create different `ThreadLocalRandom`s based on the same seed).

EDIT: As for using the same `ThreadLocalRandom` in different threads, basically, `ThreadLocalRandom` uses some magic to ensure it gets its seed from the current thread (see the implementation of `nextSeed()`).

Comment: So your suggestion is to instantiate the `ThreadLocalRandom` in the filter method (i.e. in the very thread executing the instruction) as I've written as the last code example?

Comment: This should be OK, unless somehow `System.nanoTime()` returns the same value for both of your `ThreadLocalRandom` initializations, which will result in a duplicated seed. The risk is low, but it's not impossible.

Comment: If you are _really_ worried about it, use the `java.util.secureRandomSeed` property instead.

Comment: @PiotrWilkin I don't think it is possible for `System.nanoTime` to return the same value for 2 different calls, ever.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, this sounds reasonable and is what I've expected. However, I would also like to know what are the risks of not instantiating the random in the filter method - would call to `nextDouble` result in the same numbers for different threads? I will upate the question.

Comment: It should be emphasized that you should not rely on the “magic” done by `ThreadLocalRandom`, but rather always invoke `ThreadLocalRandom.current()`. In some implementations, you get a singleton that does “magic”, in others, you get a different instance for every thread. This implementation detail doesn’t matter, as long as you use it *correctly*. As said, the way it has been used in the question’s example, i.e. calling `ThreadLocalRandom.current()` each time, is correct.

Comment: @Holger is right. You should never rely on implementation-specific behavior, that can lead to very hard-to-find bugs.